# tomcat server for setting java -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true , can you tell its been set?

Tags: tomcat, log4j2, tomcat8

I have updated the JvmOptions with -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true in the service.bat file for Tomcat.

Is there anywhere i can check this has worked successfully? i cant find anything relating to it in the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tomcat should log all applied startup parameters during startup per default into  `tomcat/logs/catalina.out`. There you should find your applied JVM Options.